# AWS- Intergrating existing backend to android project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Now I have an existing backend amw like this :
[image]

I want to integrate it to my new android project , how can i achive it ?
I am currently following this guide (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/use-existing-resources/q/platform/android) , add `amplifyconfiguration.json` but not working :

[image]

[image]

And then I tried to run command like this :
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5006

```
amplify pull --appId <correct Amplify App id> --envName <env name>
```

but still not sure where to find the appId .